# BTC-e API - Non Responsive

Tags: php, api

This is what I have to fetch the Buy and Sell values off of the BTC-e API.
http://btc-e.com/api/documentation/

```
<?
function GetJsonFeed($json_url)
{
    $feed = file_get_contents($json_url);
    return json_decode($feed, true);
}
$LTC_USD = GetJsonFeed("https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker");
$LTC_USD_BUY = $LTC_USD["ticker"]["buy"];
$LTC_USD_SELL = $LTC_USD["ticker"]["sell"];

echo "Buy: $LTC_USD_BUY";
echo "Sell: $LTC_USD_SELL";
?>
```

However, it does not seem to function.

Comment: is file_get_contents() enabled on your server?

Comment: @Pekka웃 nothing is displayed.

Comment: Well, at what point does it fail? What is the result of the file_get_contents call? What is he result of the json_decode call? Etc.

Comment: Script in action: http://gf9.freeiz.com/

Comment: @Pekka웃 No errors are displayed.

Comment: But what is the result of each call?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function getTicker($type1, $type2, $cmd)
{
    if ($type1 && $type2 && $cmd) {
        $jurl="https://btc-e.com/api/2/".$type1."_".$type2."/ticker";
        $j=file_get_contents($jurl,0,null,null);$v=json_decode($j,true);
        return $v['ticker'][$cmd];
    } else {return 0;}
}

//Examples
$EUR_LTC = getTicker("ltc", "eur", "avg");
$EUR_BTC = getTicker("btc", "eur", "avg");
$USD_LTC = getTicker("ltc", "usd", "avg");
$USD_BTC = getTicker("btc", "usd", "avg");
$BTC_LTC = getTicker("ltc", "btc", "avg");
echo 'Euro to LTC: '.$EUR_LTC;
echo 'Euro to BTC: '.$EUR_BTC;
echo 'USD to LTC: '.$USD_LTC;
echo 'USD to BTC: '.$USD_BTC;
echo 'BTC to LTC: '.$BTC_LTC;
?>
```

Comment: you can change the "avg" to anything such as "buy" / "sell" :D